# Extract chart data from Word document to CSV files automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, charts, csv, export

I have lots of charts in a Word document in `docx` format. If I click on `Edit data`, I get an Excel window which displays the data. From there, it's easy to export it to CSV.

How is it possible to export all such tabular data into CSV files automatically instead of clicking?

Answer (score 3):

First change the extension of `docx` to `zip` (or open the file otherwise). The charts are inside the `word\charts` folder. The source Excel files are inside the `word\embeddings`, and can be converted to CSV.